# $ab+bc+ca=3,$ find the minimal value $k:$ $\left(\frac{a+b}{c+ab}\right)^k+\left(\frac{c+b}{a+cb}\right)^k+\left(\frac{a+c}{b+ac}\right)^k\ge 3.$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality

Let $a,b,c\ge 0: ab+bc+ca=3.$ Find the minimal value of constant $k$ satisfying$$\left(\frac{a+b}{c+ab}\right)^k+\left(\frac{c+b}{a+cb}\right)^k+\left(\frac{a+c}{b+ac}\right)^k\ge 3.$$
I've proved when $k=\dfrac{1}{2}.$

Actually, by Holder $$\left(\sqrt{\frac{c+b}{a+cb}}\right)^2.\sum_{cyc}(b+c)^2(a+bc)(2a+b+c)^3\ge [\sum_{cyc}(b+c)(2a+b+c)]^3,$$ the following inequality is ugly but we can use $uvw.$

By checking $k=\dfrac{1}{3},$ the problem seems true but I've had no proof yet.

So, what is the range of $k$ ? Thank you very much.

**Update**

I see that when $k\ge 1$ we can use AM-GM $$\left(\frac{a+b}{c+ab}\right)^k+k-1\ge k.\frac{a+b}{c+ab}$$
Similarly, we just need to prove $$\frac{a+b}{c+ab}+\frac{c+b}{a+cb}+\frac{a+c}{b+ca}\ge 3$$But by C-S we will prove $$4(a+b+c)^2\ge 3.(6+3(a+b+c)-3abc) \iff 4(a+b+c)^2-9(a+b+c)-18+9abc\ge 0$$
Is that true approach ?

Id est, we need to consider in case $k\le 1.$

Comment: $k=0$ satisfies the inequality trivially, right?

Comment: $a=1.5, b= 1.5, c=0.25$ doesn't work for $k=-\infty$. So the minimal value must be a finite negative value.

Comment: The command of Mathematica `FindInstance[{a*b + b*c + c*a == 
    3 && ((a + b)/(c + a*b)^k + (c + b)/(a + c*b)^
        k + (a + c)/(b + a*c)^k) >= 3 && {a, b, c} > 0}, {a, b, c, k}, Reals]` performs $$\left\{\left\{a\to \frac{33456189251}{11094027091},b\to \frac{243465389}{14596681979},c\to \frac{119415632952690036407}{122762591586843015282},k\to -\frac{12994066103}{12489064990}\right\}\right\} .$$

Comment: Your inequality is a bit of stronger than old one: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1701487p10932253.

Comment: How to prove it ? @user64494

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer .

For the case $k=1/3$ use [Power mean  inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Power_Mean_Inequality) and Minkowski's inequality ($P(3^{2/3}(u+v+w)^{1/3}-|u|^{1/3}-|v|^{1/3}-|w|^{1/3})\leq 0\leq P(3^{2/3}(u-U+v-V+w-W)^{1/3}-|u-U|^{1/3}-|v-V|^{1/3}-|w-W|^{1/3})$)such that $P>0$ as we can rewrite the inequality like a difference so :

$$0\leq\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{x+y}{z+xy}-C\right)^{k} \tag{I}$$

Where :

$$C=\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{x-y}{3(x+y+z)}-1\right)^{1/k}$$

It solves some case .

---

---

To show $I$ we write :

$$a(x,y,z)=\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{x+y}{z+xy}-C\right)$$

And :

$$c(x,z)=a(x,\frac{3-xz}{x+z},z)$$

Then we have :

$$c(\frac{1}{x+1},\frac{1}{z+1})\geq 0$$

Because all the coefficients (long expression) are positive .

On the other hand we can show with the same path $C\geq 3$

Then we can try to make a contradiction using Reversed Minkowski's inequality + triangular inequality .

Comment: How can I get the detail os your last statement ?